# Text Segmentation Based On Direct Sentence

Tags: python, regex, text-segmentation

Suppose I have a docx file like this :

> When I was a young boy my father took me into the city to see a
>   marching band. 
>       He said, "Son when you grow up would you be the savior of the broken?".
>       My father sat beside me, hugging my shoulders with both of his arms.
>       I said "I Would.".
>       My father replied "That is my boy!"

And I want to segmentation the docx base on direct sentence. Like this :

> sent1 : He said, "Son when you grow up would you be the savior of the
>   broken?"
>
> sent2 : I said "I Would."
>
> sent3 : My father replied "That is my boy!"

I tried using regex. the result is this

```
When I was a young boy my father took me into the city to see a marching band.

He said, "Son when you grow up would you be the savior of the broken?

".

My father sat beside me, hugging my shoulders with both of his arms.

I said "I Would.

".

My father replied "That is my boy!
```

regex code :

```
import re
SENTENCE_REGEX = re.compile('[^!?\.]+[!?\.]')
text = open ('text.docx','r')

def parse_sentences(text):
   return [x.lstrip() for x in SENTENCE_REGEX.findall(text)]

def print_sentences(sentences):
    print ("\n\n".join(sentences))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_sentences(parse_sentences(text))
```

Comment: `I tried using regex.` With what code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt = '''When I was a young boy my father took me into the city to see a marching band. He said, "Son when you grow up would you be the savior of the broken?" My father sat beside me, hugging my shoulders with both of his arms. I said "I Would." My father replied "That is my boy!"'''

pttrn = re.compile(r'(\.|\?|\!)(\'|\")?\s')

new = re.sub(pttrn, r'\1\2\n\n', txt)

print(new)
```

Output:

```
When I was a young boy my father took me into the city to see a marching band.

He said, "Son when you grow up would you be the savior of the broken?".

My father sat beside me, hugging my shoulders with both of his arms.


I said "I Would."

My father replied "That is my boy!"
```

PS:
As far as I know, endings like `?".`, `.".` or `!".` are not allowed in English.

Comment: and how do I group it based on direct sentence?

Comment: @SyafiqurRahman lst = output.slip("\n\n")

Comment: Slip? Did you mean split? 'cause when I tried, no attribute Slip.

Comment: @SyafiqurRahman Yes I do mean split. Sorry for the typo. You can split a string into a list of strings based on any delimiter.